# DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator : Error in pysparkJob template

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

Hello fellow Stackoverflowers,

I have been trying to use the `DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator` to run a pyspark job. Sadly after following all the documentation I am getting error in Composer `ValueError: Protocol message OrderedJob has no "stepID" field.`

Here is the template that I am using.

```
{
  "id": "my-workflow-template",
  "jobs": [
    {
      "stepID": "123456dfgy",
      "pysparkJob": {
        "mainPythonFileUri": "gs://gcp-gmp/app.py"
      }
    }
  ],
  "name": "My Workflow Template",
  "placement": {
    "managedCluster": {
      "clusterName": "my-managed-cluster",
      "config": {
        "master_config": {
          "disk_config": {
            "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024,
            "boot_disk_type": "pd-standard"
          },
          "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
          "num_instances": 1
        },
        "worker_config": {
          "disk_config": {
            "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024,
            "boot_disk_type": "pd-standard"
          },
          "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
          "num_instances": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the entire python code.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime ,timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

DAG_ID= 'Dataproc_Instantiate_Inline_Workflow_TemplateOper_example'

JSON_CONTENT = """{
  "id": "my-workflow-template",
  "jobs": [
    {
      "stepID": "123456dfgy",
      "pysparkJob": {
        "mainPythonFileUri": "gs://my-bucket/app.py"
      }
    }
  ],
  "name": "My Workflow Template",
  "placement": {
    "managedCluster": {
      "clusterName": "my-managed-cluster",
      "config": {
        "master_config": {
          "disk_config": {
            "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024,
            "boot_disk_type": "pd-standard"
          },
          "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
          "num_instances": 1
        },
        "worker_config": {
          "disk_config": {
            "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024,
            "boot_disk_type": "pd-standard"
          },
          "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
          "num_instances": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}"""


template_dict = json.loads(JSON_CONTENT)

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 6, 29),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = DAG_ID,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
)


start = DummyOperator(
    task_id = 'start',
    dag = dag

)


create_dataproc_template = DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator(
        template = template_dict,
        task_id = 'create_dataproc_template',
        project_id=  'my-project',
        region = 'us-central1',
        gcp_conn_id = 'google_cloud_default',
        dag = dag
 )

complete = DummyOperator(
    task_id = 'complete',
    trigger_rule = TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED,
    dag = dag
)


start >> create_dataproc_template >> complete
```

Strangely when I was not using the stepID field the error was `ValueError: Protocol message OrderedJob has no "pysparkJob" field.`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot of research and trial and error, I discovered that the keys we provided in the config JSON differ from those described in the Google documentation.

While running this from Composer/ Airflow we have to make the keys from camel case to snake case. e.g. stepID --> step_id

I am providing the correct JSON here :

```
{
   "id":"my-workflow-template",
   "jobs":[
      {
         "step_id":"123456dfgy",
         "pyspark_job":{
            "main_python_file_uri":"gs://my-bucket/app.py"
         }
      }
   ],
   "placement":{
      "managed_cluster":{
         "cluster_name":"my-managed-cluster",
         "config":{
            "master_config":{
               "disk_config":{
                  "boot_disk_size_gb":1024,
                  "boot_disk_type":"pd-standard"
               },
               "machine_type_uri":"n1-standard-4",
               "num_instances":1
            },
            "worker_config":{
               "disk_config":{
                  "boot_disk_size_gb":1024,
                  "boot_disk_type":"pd-standard"
               },
               "machine_type_uri":"n1-standard-4",
               "num_instances":2
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```